# Reason for delay in fsync commit log

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have set `periodic` in `commitlog_sync` and it periodically does the fsync in commit log but I often see the following kind of Warning messages in logs.

```
WARN  [PERIODIC-COMMIT-LOG-SYNCER] 2018-05-23 08:59:19,075 NoSpamLogger.java:94 - Out of 1 commit log syncs over the past 0s with average duration of 13038.00ms, 1 have exceeded the configured commit interval by an average of 3038.00ms
```

1) What could be the reason for this?
2) How to rectify this error?

Comment: 13s flush is really bad, horrible disks?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I could see other IO operations are fine, so How can I track this and find the solution for this

Comment: whats load like? any iowait spikes? if it takes >10s to write to disk what has been inserted in 10s your hardware simply cant keep up. If its regular that is. If this is very sporadic in logs maybe just decrease memtable sizes

Comment: I decreased the memtable size and observed this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509733/cassandra-tuning-for-request-timed-out

Comment: From GC logs in other question: `Total time for which application threads were stopped: 9.2242037 seconds, Stopping threads took: 9.2232493 seconds` can easily explain this. I would still lean towards bad hardware though, as this was not a GC but just a random safepoint (revoke thread bias maybe?) and theres zero reasons for it to take that long. _Most likely_ but not only cause is a fsync is being blocked, and in a native with GC locker so not in safe point. If its an ssd perhaps a blocking trim, could be high load or an OS resource starvation, something outside C* though.