# Cassandra tuning for Request timed out

Tags: java, linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am using **Apache Cassandra** as a data store for one of my project, It is a single node and running smoothly for 4 to 5 hours then I started getting the **Request timed out error**.

I observed the following in the last week and tuned all

1) **GC pause** was taking a long time and I tuned the GC pause and currently it is not even taking 2 seconds.

**PF the GC logs for reference** : https://files.fm/u/h8b2mnwm#_

2) Memory is not even using above 5GB of 8GB allocated
3) CPU with 8 cores seems fine.

[image]

If everything seems proper, What is the next thing I need to look in Cassandra to solve the **Request timed out.**

**NOTE** :
    i) READ / WRITE timeout is 60 seconds.
    ii) Single Write with partition key gives Request timed out

Comment: More often than not, `request timed out` usually happens from querying too many rows at once, or trying to run a query on a table that wasn't designed to serve it.

Comment: @Aaron This table has 600K entries, each entry has its unique partition key (there is no clustering key for this table). It is failed in INSERT query with the request timed out.
One more point, Request timed out error is not seen in the cassandra debug logs, It is received in the Cassandra driver.

Comment: @Aaron Is that request timed out related to connection in Cassandra? When this error happens?

Comment: @Aaron If you need any other details please let me know, I will provide. Any help is much appreciated.